# java - replaceAll anything in between known boundaries including newlines and multiple tabs

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I want to replace the highlighted sections in the first figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmtSz.png) (starting with `:g` anything in between including newline and multiple tabs, and ending with `:`) with the highlighted sections in the second figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPvY1.png) (`:o`).

**Before:**
[image: first figure]

**After:**
[image: second figure]
I tried `replaceAll(":g.*?:", ":o")` but didn't work due to newline and tabs, then I tried something like `replaceAll(":g.*?]\n\t\t\t:", ":o")` but the number of tabs can vary so I need something to replace all tabs in this highlighted section.

```html
try {
  
     File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/eddy/1.xml");
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
     
     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
     
     System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("feature_tree").item(0).getTextContent());

     String fm = doc.getElementsByTagName("feature_tree").item(0).getTextContent();
     
     fm = fm.replaceAll(":g[^:]*:", ":o");
     
     System.out.println(fm);
     
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
       }
          
          
          
          
 :r DataMining(_r)
 :m InputData(_r_1)
  :m Attribute types(_r_1_35)
   :o Mixed attribute types(_r_1_141_151_157_158)
   :g _r_1_35_36(_r_1_35_36) [1,*] 
    : Discrete(_r_1_35_36_39)
     :g _r_1_35_36_39_41(_r_1_35_36_39_41) [1,*] 
      : Nominal(_r_1_35_36_39_41_43)
      : Ordinal(_r_1_35_36_39_41_44)
    : Numerical(_r_1_35_36_40)
     :g _r_1_35_36_40_45(_r_1_35_36_40_45) [1,*] 
      : Bounded(_r_1_35_36_40_45_46)
      : Unbounded(_r_1_35_36_40_45_47)
    : Text(_r_1_35_36_55)
    : Time(_r_1_35_36_58)
  :m Data properties(_r_1_141)
   :o Labeled data(_r_1_141_144)
    :o More than two classes(_r_1_141_144_154)
   :o Missing values present(_r_1_141_145)
   :o Independant attributes(_r_1_141_150)
   :o Standardized values(_r_1_141_155)
  :m Data Sets(_r_1_151)
   :g _r_11_35_36_40_45(_r_11_35_36_40_45) [1,*] 
    : Training set(_r_1_151_152)
     :m Number of instances(_r_1_151_152_168)
      :g _r_1_151_152_168_170(_r_1_151_152_168_170) [1,1] 
       : 1-50(_r_1_151_152_168_170_171)
       : 51-250(_r_11_151_152_168_170_172)
       : 251-1000(_r_12_151_152_168_170_172)
       : 1001-10000(_r_1_151_152_168_170_173)
       : 10001-100000(_r_1_151_152_168_170_174)
       : 100001-(_r_1_151_152_168_170_175)
    : Test set(_r_1_151_153)
```

Comment: Try `replaceAll(":g[^:]+:", ":o")`. Or maybe even `.replaceAll("(?m)^(\\s*):g[^:]+:", "$1:o")` to make it safer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew both didn't work

Comment: Eddy, "didn't work" is not a clear feedback. What happens? Post the code you have.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I added the code and the String to a snippet

Comment: I don't think regex are the appropriate solution here. Storing your data into a tree or a proper object should do a much better job. EDIT : something like : create your own Tree implementation, in which you would fill line after line your whole data set, and override the add method to modify behaviour when the line starts with `:g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a regex is the proper solution, but if your requirements never change `replaceAll(":g[^:]*:",":o")` should do the trick.

Test :

```
public static void main(String t[]) throws IOException {
    Path exampleFile = Paths.get(PATH_TO_YOUR_EXAMPLE_AS_TEXT);
    String dataAsString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(exampleFile));
    System.out.println(dataAsString);
    System.out.println(dataAsString.replaceAll(":g[^:]*:", ":o"));

}
```

Prints :

```
:r DataMining(_r)
:m InputData(_r_1)
    :m Attribute types(_r_1_35)
        :o Mixed attribute types(_r_1_141_151_157_158)
        :g _r_1_35_36(_r_1_35_36) [1,*] 
            : Discrete(_r_1_35_36_39)
                :g _r_1_35_36_39_41(_r_1_35_36_39_41) [1,*] 
                    : Nominal(_r_1_35_36_39_41_43)
                    : Ordinal(_r_1_35_36_39_41_44)
            : Numerical(_r_1_35_36_40)
                :g _r_1_35_36_40_45(_r_1_35_36_40_45) [1,*] 
                    : Bounded(_r_1_35_36_40_45_46)
                    : Unbounded(_r_1_35_36_40_45_47)
            : Text(_r_1_35_36_55)
            : Time(_r_1_35_36_58)
    :m Data properties(_r_1_141)
        :o Labeled data(_r_1_141_144)
            :o More than two classes(_r_1_141_144_154)
        :o Missing values present(_r_1_141_145)
        :o Independant attributes(_r_1_141_150)
        :o Standardized values(_r_1_141_155)
    :m Data Sets(_r_1_151)
        :g _r_11_35_36_40_45(_r_11_35_36_40_45) [1,*] 
            : Training set(_r_1_151_152)
                :m Number of instances(_r_1_151_152_168)
                    :g _r_1_151_152_168_170(_r_1_151_152_168_170) [1,1] 
                        : 1-50(_r_1_151_152_168_170_171)
                        : 51-250(_r_11_151_152_168_170_172)
                        : 251-1000(_r_12_151_152_168_170_172)
                        : 1001-10000(_r_1_151_152_168_170_173)
                        : 10001-100000(_r_1_151_152_168_170_174)
                        : 100001-(_r_1_151_152_168_170_175)
            : Test set(_r_1_151_153)
:r DataMining(_r)
:m InputData(_r_1)
    :m Attribute types(_r_1_35)
        :o Mixed attribute types(_r_1_141_151_157_158)
        :o Discrete(_r_1_35_36_39)
                :o Nominal(_r_1_35_36_39_41_43)
                    : Ordinal(_r_1_35_36_39_41_44)
            : Numerical(_r_1_35_36_40)
                :o Bounded(_r_1_35_36_40_45_46)
                    : Unbounded(_r_1_35_36_40_45_47)
            : Text(_r_1_35_36_55)
            : Time(_r_1_35_36_58)
    :m Data properties(_r_1_141)
        :o Labeled data(_r_1_141_144)
            :o More than two classes(_r_1_141_144_154)
        :o Missing values present(_r_1_141_145)
        :o Independant attributes(_r_1_141_150)
        :o Standardized values(_r_1_141_155)
    :m Data Sets(_r_1_151)
        :o Training set(_r_1_151_152)
                :m Number of instances(_r_1_151_152_168)
                    :o 1-50(_r_1_151_152_168_170_171)
                        : 51-250(_r_11_151_152_168_170_172)
                        : 251-1000(_r_12_151_152_168_170_172)
                        : 1001-10000(_r_1_151_152_168_170_173)
                        : 10001-100000(_r_1_151_152_168_170_174)
                        : 100001-(_r_1_151_152_168_170_175)
            : Test set(_r_1_151_153)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy `replaceAll(":g[^:]*:", ":o")` worked, if you can update your answer to consider it as correct. However, I still agree with you that storing the string in a tree is the best solution since I can handle indentations in a better way.

Comment: Is the answer still lacking something ?